# How to add export PATH in Qt pro file

Tags: c++, qt, environment-variables, qmake

In Qt5 Linux I have to add path to the environment so I usually do

```
export PATH=path_to_subsitute:$PATH
make
```

because I have to put it before the other path variable.

Is there a way to add it directly to the `.pro` file? I don't wan to add it in the project settings because it changes only the `.pro.user` .

Comment: Maybe `export(path_to_subsitute:$$(PATH))`?

Comment: @vahancho nothing change

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [system()](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qmake-function-reference.html#system-command) function within your .pro file. Make sure that you make it conditional for your host or target platform.

Comment: Yes, but it has to be executed before the make generation or the export does not apply